# Dart How to prevent chrome back to previous page when user press DELETE or BACKSPACE

Tags: dart

How can I prevent browser back to previous page when user press BACKSPACE or DELETE in Dart?

I have listening key events like this:

```
// Keyboard event
streamsubKey = window.onKeyUp.listen((KeyboardEvent e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
       case KeyCode.BACKSPACE:
       case KeyCode.DELETE:
            // do something and stop browser back to previous.
       break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`case KeyCode.BACKSPACE:` should be enough, `delete` doesn't navigate anywhere.

Just add `e.preventDefault();`.

You probably also want to skip `e.preventDefault();` when the current element is an input element or a textarea.

```
if(!(e.target is InputElement || e.target is TextArea)) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

**not tested**

Comment: I add KeyCode.DELETE because for mac.
Tested e.preventDefault(), it is not work under chrome.

Comment: Ok, what does Mac do with delete?

Comment: I tested DELETE key cause browser (except Safari) back to previous page.
e.preventDefault(); Can prevent browser back action (except Chrome), it still back to prevent page if user click more than once.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `onKeyPress` might be a better fit than `onKeyUp`. I saw examples where they listen to all three `onKeyDown`, `onKeyPress`, and `onKeyUp`. As mentioned I haven't used this myself yet and it's not tested.

Comment: After tested onKeyUp onKeyDown or onKeyPress cannot prevent the back action. But I tested a workarround, after e.preventDefault( ) use window.history.forward() to force forward action when user agent is chrome. Like this:  
if (window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > 0) window.history.forward();